# Multiple INSERT INTO in one query but with a change of one field

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

I want to create a program with multiples engines and where each engine can contain some elements, so I create a database with three tables :

- Engine(engine_id, engine_name,...)
- Elements(element_id, element_name, ...)
- Selected_Elements(selected_element_id, *engine_id*, *element_id*)

The user can then create new engines or load one, add or del some elements of this engine, and create new elements (or edit olds). Now, when the user create a new engine, he can decide to start from another engine.

In the Engine table, it just need to create a new Engine with same name, description, ...
But I don't know how to add in Selected_elements, the selected_elements of the old engine but with the new engine id. I want to do something like this:

```
// I have 2 entries $_POST["engine_name"] (the new name for the new engine) and ["_template_engine_id"] wich contains the id of the old engine to copy

// Create the new engine && get the id
$request = "INSERT INTO engine(name) VALUES (".$_POST["engine_name"].")";
$database->exec($request);  
$id = $database->lastInsertId();

// Duplicate all selected_elements with old engine_id 
$request =  "INSERT INTO selected_elements(engine_id,element_id) SELECT ".$id.", element_id FROM selected_elements where engine_id = ".$_POST["_template_engine_id"];
```

The last `$request` is the subject of this topic, I want to "duplicate" all old-engine-selected-elements and give them the new-engine_id. I don't know how doing that because I'm pretty sure this way is wrong^^'

Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are more `selected` elements which need to be duplicated for the new engine, you can't insert them in a single instance. Do this instead:

```
    // fetch all elements from the old engine
    $query = "SELECT * FROM selected_elements where engine_id = ".$_POST['_template_engine_id'];    

    $rows = $database->exec($query)->fetch_assoc(); 
    // or whatever your fetch handle is 
    foreach ($rows as $row) {

        // add old element_id to new engine $id
        $request =  "INSERT INTO selected_elements(engine_id,element_id) VALUES ('".$id."','".$row['element_id']."')";
        $database->exec($request);

    }
```

Comment: Yep i knew this way but i tried to make it shorter because in fact i have many differents Elements so many differents table Element_A, sleected_element_A, element_b, selected_element_b, ...
But if it's not possible i'll do your way !
 Thank you

Comment: Hm, I guess you could improve that SQL structure.